# Restrict users to create files on Samba share by file extensions

Tags: windows, samba

I'm having a network of users where all windows machines have a samba share attached. These users are not allowed to share specific files with file extensions like ".bat" or ".ps1". Is there any way to restrict this with samba so they cannot create files like this?

Comment: You are fighting a losing battle. They will just give it a different extension.